# Get session id of opened cursor in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-cursor

In Oracel `V$OPEN_CURSOR` include a sid field, but the `pg_cursors` table in Postgres has no connection with other system catalogs. Is it possible to get such information in PostgreSQL? If i clearly understand, there are no session ids in PostgreSQL and usualy using backend pid. I have get a list of tables with opened cursors, but it can not help me, because there is no connection between `pg_tables` and `pg_stat_activity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, a cursor only exists in and for the current database connection. So the session that can use a cursor is always only the one that opened it. You can see all open cursors of the current session in the view `pg_cursors`. Since this information is not stored in shared memory, there is no way to see the cursors for a different database connection.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to get a list of cursors for all connections?

Comment: No, because cursors are local to a connection, so they are not stored in shared memory.